# IMU data to be used with robot_localization

Tags: imu, navigation, ros-melodic, acceleration, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the package [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) with an IMU. In the docs, the [Preparing Your Data for Use with robot_localization](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html#imu), it says

> **Adherence to specifications:** As with odometry, be sure your data adheres to REP-103 and the sensor_msgs/Imu specification. Double-check the signs of your data, and make sure the frame_id values are correct.

REP-103 says the axes should be oriented in the following fashion:

- x forward
- y left
- z up

Which means when an IMU is placed in its neutral position (flat on the surface), the axes should look like this:

[image]

So for acceleration due to gravity, it should measure - (minus) 9.8 meters per second squared for the Z axis. However the docs say:

> **Acceleration**: Be careful with acceleration data. The state estimation nodes in robot_localization assume that an IMU that is placed in its neutral right-side-up position on a flat surface will:

> - Measure +9.81 meters per second squared for the Z axis.
> - If the sensor is rolled +90 degrees (left side up), the acceleration should be +9.81 meters per second squared for the Y axis.
> - If the sensor is pitched +90 degrees (front side down), it should read -9.81 meters per second squared for the X axis.

This would mean the axes are oriented in the following manner, implying left handed coordinate system:

[image]

I am definitely missing something here. Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298415/imu-data-to-be-used-with-robot_localization/) by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 512 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) on 2018-07-24**:
[@Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) I avoided posting an issue in the robot_localization repository since most recent issues have been directed towards answers.ros.org. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer to my question. See these 2 posts:

1. [IMU convention for robot_localization](https://answers.ros.org/question/269030/imu-convention-for-robot_localization/)
2. [Why do 3-axis accelerometers seemingly have a left-handed coordinate system?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/why-do-3-axis-accelerometers-seemingly-have-a-left-handed-coordinate-system)

To summarize, in static condition the IMU measures the opposite of gravity acceleration.

---

Originally posted by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) with karma: 512 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2018-07-24**:
That's the perfect answer to the question. Thanks for taking the time to answer your own question and helping others! :)

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-07-30**:
Apologies for not responding in a timely fashion, but I'm glad you were able to track down the correct answer!